# 404 Not Found nginx/1.15.9 (Ubuntu)

Tags: nginx

I am running a PHP Website Where all Sub Pages are showing 404 Not Found nginx/1.15.9 (Ubuntu) But Homepage and Admin Panel {example.com/admin} is working fine. I am running Php website which is running on Nginx Server -

Here is my Default Nginx File

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
#SSL configuration
#
#listen 443 ssl default_server;
#listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
#
#Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
#See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
#
#Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
#See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
#
#Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package 
#Don't use them in a production server! 
#
#include snippets/snakeoil.conf; 
root /var/www/html; 
# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP 
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
server_name (My IP Pasted here);
location / {
# First attempt to serve request as file, then
# as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
# pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
#
location ~ \.php$ {
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

# With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
# With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
#fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
deny all;
}}
```

And Nginx.conf file as

```
user www-data;  
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
events {
worker_connections 1000;
# multi_accept on;
}
http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Homepage Working Fine But other pages are not working fornt-end pages are showing as

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.15.9 (Ubuntu)
```

My website is hosted on Digitalocean where I simply create droplet then Install Nginx, MySql, PHP-FPM 7.2, PhpMyAdmin. And Then Copy PHP Files into /var/www/html

and the PHP project is working fine on Xamp where all pages are working fine without any error. I am just receiving error on nginx server. Please Anyone Help -

Here is IP - 134.209.36.248 {URL}

Comment: Check the error log.

Comment: Error Log ===> 

2019/05/02 01:57:29 [emerg] 14537#14537: unexpected end of file, expecting "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:92
2019/05/02 01:59:13 [notice] 14565#14565: signal process started
2019/05/02 02:02:06 [notice] 15984#15984: signal process started
2019/05/02 02:21:13 [notice] 26291#26291: signal process started
2019/05/02 02:24:54 [notice] 26307#26307: signal process started
2019/05/02 02:32:12 [notice] 26333#26333: signal process started
2019/05/03 02:11:48 [notice] 2385#2385: signal process started

Answer (score 0):

sudo nano +92 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

add a } to get the server up again.